# CasperJS' scrollToBottom is not working when populating the complete page from infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, casperjs, infinite-scroll

I don't have any idea why scrollToBottom() is not working. I want to keep scrolling to bottom of the page if the current data (from evaluate) is greater than previous data.

PhantomJS 2.0.0
CasperJS 1.1.0-beta3

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'info',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
    }
});

casper.options.waitTimeout = 60000;
var utils = require('utils');
var hospitals = [];
var prevTotalHospitals = 0;
var currentTotalHospitals = 0;

casper.start('https://www.docdoc.com/').thenClick("#form-submit-btn").then(function() {
    this.wait(5000);
    this.scrollToBottom();
    processPage();
});

casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){
    this.echo("remote> " + msg);
});

casper.on('step.error', function(err) {
    this.die("Step has failed: " + err);
})

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.on('complete.error', function(err) {
    this.die("Complete callback has failed: " + err);
});

casper.run(function(){
    utils.dump(hospitals);
});

function getCurrentTotalHospitals(){
    var resultsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div.results-list div.result");
    return resultsNodeList.length;
}

function getDetails(){
    var details = [];
    var resultsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div.results-list div.result");
    console.log("resultsNodeList.length " + resultsNodeList.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < resultsNodeList.length; i++) {
        var detail = {
            "name"          : resultsNodeList[i].querySelector("h2.link").textContent.replace(/\n/g, ''),
            "country"       : resultsNodeList[i].querySelector("h3.country").textContent.replace(/\n/g, ''),
            "specialities"  : resultsNodeList[i].querySelector("div.specialities").textContent.replace(/\n/g, ''),
            "language"      : resultsNodeList[i].querySelector("div.language").textContent.replace(/\n/g, '')
        };
        details.push(detail);
    };

    return JSON.stringify(details);
}

function stopScript() {
    utils.dump(hospitals);
    console.log("Exiting..." + hospitals.length);
    casper.exit();
};

function processPage() {
    currentTotalHospitals = casper.evaluate(getCurrentTotalHospitals);
    console.log(currentTotalHospitals + " <> " + prevTotalHospitals);
    if (currentTotalHospitals > prevTotalHospitals) {
        prevTotalHospitals = currentTotalHospitals;
        hospitals = hospitals.concat(casper.evaluate(getDetails));
        casper.scrollToBottom();
        casper.wait(5000);
        processPage();
    } else {
        stopScript();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`evaluate()` is a synchronous function. Since it is used synchronously inside of `processPage()`, `processPage()` is also synchronous at the beginning. Later you're using `wait()` which is ***a***synchronous. The `processPage()` that comes after `wait()` is executed immediately.

You can use it in this way:

```
if (...) {
    ...
    casper.scrollToBottom();
    casper.wait(5000, processPage);
} else {...}
```

By the way, the same is true for the first `wait()`. It should be:

```
this.wait(5000, function(){
    this.scrollToBottom();
    processPage();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Artjom , I have changed my code based on your suggestion, but unfortunately is not working as intented. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Code : http://cryptb.in/Ujxrl4#d28477bf1777f77ff6632bfc491b89c5  
Log : http://cryptb.in/IRxbi#4156c977fceb2f86bf646993b406fcbd

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the issue might be.